# pull Distinct records from DB using two columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a need to pull records from a DB, let's assume this structure

ID,Name,Type,Key,ExpDate,IsActive

Now Some restructuring was done and there is a possibility that the table will hold duplicate records based on ID and Type.  I want to be able to pull the records from the DB using linq, but only one of the records that have the same ID/Type.

EX:

1, Fred, 1, NewGuid, 12/15/2019, 1

1, Fred, 1, NewGuid, 10/01/2017, 1

2, Goerge, 2, NewGuid, 02/01/2018, 1

I want the result set to be 1 record for Fred and One for Goerge.  It doesn't matter really which of the Fred records gets return just that only one does.

I've tried using DISTINCT, but that returns a IDistinct and not the entire record.  Is there a way to do this using linq?

Here is what I've tried:

```
_table.AllReadOnly().Where(i => i.ID == id && i.IsActive).GroupBy(i => i.ID, i.Type).Select(i => i.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
_table.AllReadOnly().Where(i => i.ID == id && i.IsActive).Distinct().ToList();
```

I know the .Distinct() like that won't do anything.  I tried figuring out how to do an EqualityComparer, but I'm not sure if that's the route I should be going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` by those 2 columns, and then from each group, select the first element. For example:

```
var list = new List<Table1>()
{
    new Table1(){ Column1="x", Column2="y", Column3= "z"},
    new Table1(){ Column1="x", Column2="y", Column3= "t"},
    new Table1(){ Column1="a", Column2="b", Column3= "c"},
};

var resulut = list.GroupBy(x => new { C1 = x.Column1, C2 = x.Column2 })
                  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

And the result would be a list containing first and third element of input list.

Comment: Thanks, That worked.  I wonder why that worked vs the way I had it.  Mine just returned a List<int?>.

Comment: You're welcome. You have passed ` i.Type` as result selector in group by signature. You don't need it.